# Istio Ingress Gateway not working in Anthos

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-anthos, istio-gateway

I created a cluster in GKE - (Google Kubernetes Engine)
Folowed the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/quickstart-asm
but used my own deployment files.
I deployed these service and gateway file.

Partial Service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-microservice-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: node-microservice
  # type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: tcp-node
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      # nodePort: 30000

---
```

Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: backend-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "backend.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress
spec:
  hosts:
    - "backend.com"
  gateways:
    - backend-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/node"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: node-microservice-service
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/java"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: java-microservice-service
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/golang"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: golang-microservice-service
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/python"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: python-microservice-service
    - route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: python-microservice-service
```

I am using the proper IP address and host together still unable to reach the microservices through the istio ingress gateway service.

Comment: Hello @user1519783, you said that you are unable to reach the microservices. Do you have any error when you try to access? Any response code? How did you try to access your microservices? Maybe do you have any logs? Please edit your question and add more information.